# Catalyst::Plugin::I18N doesn't work properly with HTML::FormFu

Tags: perl, internationalization, catalyst, html-formfu

I'm setup a new project with Catalyst with the Plugin Catalyst::Plugin::I18N and creating forms with HTML::FormFu my problem is that localization with the HTML::FormFu config files doesn't work.

I create my language files like written here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::I18N::Manual

I tried solutions like localize_class or add_localize_class_from_object but none didn't work

My Form config file looks like this:

```
action:
indicator: submit
auto_fieldset: 1
elements:
  - type: Text
    name: email
    id: email
    label_loc: form.add_user.email.label
    constraints:
      - type: Required
        message_loc: form.add_user.email.constraint.required
      - type: Email
        message_loc: form.add_user.email.constraint.email
    error_tag: div
    render_method: tt
    attributes_xml: { class: form-control }
container_attributes: { class: form-group }
```

The Action in the Catalyst Controller (I'm using Catalyst::Controller::HTML::FormFu)

```perl
sub add_user :Path('/admin/add/user') :FormConfig {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    my $form        = $c->stash->{'form'};
    $form->get_field('submit')->value($c->loc('form.add_user.submit.value'));
    return if !$form->submitted_and_valid;
}
```

Content of the de.po File:

```
#: root/forms/admin/add_user.yml:9
msgid "form.add_user.email.label"
msgstr "E-Mail Adresse"
```

It displays all the Time: form.add_user.email.label instead of: E-Mail Adresse